# What is the purpose of the last two lines of code

Tags: python, class, init

I am trying to characterise my class with init but the website says I have to add the last two lines of code but I don't know what they do? Could someone explain?
Code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def myfunc(self):
        print("My awesome name is " + self.name)

p1 = Person("bob", 69)
p1.myfunc()
```

Comment: Yes, but you first. What does it look like is happening?

Comment: they instantiate your object and call your function. A function is useless if you don't call it.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple. Let's say you create a string.

```
a = "Hello"
```

This basically creates a new string `object` called `a`. Now you can use a variety of functions like `.isdigit()`, `.isalnum()` etc. These functions are basically the functions of the String `class` and when called, they perform the function in relation to the object they are associated with.
So Saying,

```
print(a.isalnum())
```

Would give `True` as the function is defined to check of the `String object` is alphanumeric.
In the same way,

```
p1 = Person("bob", 69) 
p1.myfunc()
```

First-line creates a new `Person` object with `name='bob'` and `age=69`. The second line then calls the function `myfunc()` in association with the Person `p1` and executes with the attributes of `p1` as its own local variables.

Answer (score 0):

The first chunk of code is defining a class. This says what the class should be called, what attributes it has, and defines its behaviour.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def myfunc(self):
        print("My awesome name is " + self.name)
```

Once those lines are run, the *class* exists in your session, but no instances of it do.

This creates an instance of the class:

```py
p1 = Person("bob", 69)
```

And this line is that instance calling its method `myfunc()`:

```py
p1.myfunc()
```